# How to mock firebase's onAuthStateChanged when using react testing library and jest

Tags: reactjs, firebase, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am trying to test my react application, which uses firebase, but my function mocks for `onAuthStateChanged` return an error `TypeError: _firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged is not a function`. Here is my implementation of the mock

```
jest.mock("../../../firebase", () => ({
  auth: jest.fn(() => ({
    onAuthStateChanged: jest.fn(),
  })),
}));
```

And here is my firebase configuration

```
const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = app.auth();
const storage = app.storage();
const firestore = app.firestore();

const realtimeDb = app.database();

const chats = {
  users: realtimeDb.ref("users/"),
  conversations: realtimeDb.ref("conversations/"),
  userConversations: realtimeDb.ref("userconversations/"),
  timeStamp: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
};

const database = {
  conversations: firestore.collection("conversations"),
  timeStamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
  formatDocument: (doc) => {
    return { id: doc.id, ...doc.data() };
  },
};

export { auth, database, storage, chats, firebase };
```

I `onAuthStateChanged` in the `AuthContext`, which is wrapped around the entire application. Here is how I implement it

```
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      setCurrentUser(user);
      setLoading(false);
    });
    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);
```

Comment: Where and how did you use `onAuthStateChanged`?

Comment: @slideshowp2 I use it in a context provider, I have updated the question to provide more details and implementation code

Comment: Try `jest.spyOn(auth, 'onAuthStateChanged')`

Comment: Okay, I have tried the solution `jest.spyOn(auth, 'onAuthStateChanged')`, but I get the error `Invalid variable access: auth`. I then moved `auth` to a variable prefixed by `mock` as suggested in the jest error message, the error is gone, but the original error message is now back `TypeError: _firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged is not a function`